# My samsung note 1 can't find the Play store and service after a factory reset

Tags: google-play-store

For a week I have been having issues with Google play store not working along with most my Google apps. Tonight I factory reset my phone to see if that would fix the issue but I made it worse.  Now my Google play services,and Google play store are gone and there is no market app either!

How do I reinstall Google play so I can start reinstalling all my other apps!

Comment: Try restarting your phone, most problems go away that way.

Comment: I have numerous times! I've tried just powering down, rebooting, I've even taken the battery out for15mins and nothing! Thank you though for trying to help me!

Comment: @KimberlySacchetti: Try flashing the firware from sammobile.com it should solve the problem.

Comment: @Kimberly please include some more details, such : custom or stock rom & version, whether or not you disabled/uninstalled any apps, and any other information that would pertinent.

Comment: Hi, I know my phone is rooted, (whatever that means) , something about custom os, its a second hand phone, I seem to have uninstalled Google play, market, therefore I cannot seem to really do much.I cannot download any apps, ALL OF MY APPS ARE GONE!!

Comment: The version of Note 1 thst my phone is , SGH-I7I7M. Also I don't know what it means or know how to flash the firmware. I need specific, exact step by step instructions please!!!